# Header tableViewCell that sits on top of tableview and doesn't scroll but other cells scroll underneath it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Title is pretty self explanatory. Header tableViewCell that sits on top of tableview and doesn't scroll but other cells scroll underneath it.

Comment: Please clarify it little more? Does you header stick completely? or it sticks on the top of the tableview when scrolling up?

Comment: Show your code how you are setting the header.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/B5GTCgYt

Answer (score 1):

Section headers of UITableView have the property of sticking above the section till the section is in scroll or visible.
The rows will scroll underneath it if u have selected plain mode in UITableView.
If you want your section header to be scrollable just like your normal rows then use Grouped mode for UITableView.

Comment: my header just scrolls by default and i have the tableview style set to  plain

Comment: i am programatically setting and removing it so i cannot use the build in method

Comment: Try using the -(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
}

Comment: Add your whole code to generate the header view inside this UITableView delegate method except the line
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;

add add - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section for giving header height

Comment: that doesnt even show up as a method in the new xcode

Comment: are you sure you're using the most up to date version of xcode because those methods aren't even being called. I am deving for ios 9+